# Let $F = Z_5[x]/(x^3-x^2-1) = Z_5(u)$ where $u = [x]$ Give a basis for $F$ over $Z_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

How can you have $Z_5([x])$ when x is not any particular element?

Comment: $u=[x]$ probably stands for the coset $x+(x^3-x^2-1)$ so it *is* a very particular element! Don't make the mistake of thinking of $x$ as a variable ranging over $\Bbb{Z}_5$. That is quite the wrong point of view here. The use of $x$ here is somewhat similar to that in: "$\{1,x,x^2\}$ is a basis for the space of polynomials of degree at most two over the reals". There $x$ does not have a particular (real) value either. Bringing it up because you may have seen that in linear algebra?

Comment: $u$ is the class of $x$ in the quotient ring of the polynomial ring $\Bbb F_5[5]$ w.r.t the (principal) ideal generated by the polynomial $x^3-x^2-1$, well, in this case i would denote this ideal by $(x^3-x^2-1)\Bbb F_5[x]$ explicitly. We use maybe the letter $J$ for it in the sequel. Then $\Bbb F_5[x]/J$ is a field, because $(x^3-x^2-1)$ is prime, because it is irreducible, because there are no roots of it in $\Bbb F_5$. A basis of this field (seen as a vector space over $\Bbb F_5$) is $1, u, u^2$.

Comment: The only way I know how to solve a question like this, is if $u$ is algebraic over $Z_5$. However the class $[x]$ can't be a root in $Z_5[x]$ right? So is that not the way to proceed in this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the polynomial $f=x^3-x^2-1\in \Bbb{F}_5[x]$. Checking each element in $\Bbb F_5$, we see $f$ has no roots, and is thus irreducible. To adjoin an element $u$ to $\Bbb{F}_5$, such that $\Bbb{F}_5(u)$ has a root for $x^3-x^2-1$ in  $\Bbb{F}_5(u)[x]$ we simply take
$$\Bbb{F}_5[x]/(x^3-x^2-1),$$
where the coset $[x]$ is the root we desired. We then denote $[x]:=u$. Now $\Bbb{F}_5(u)$ is a field extension of $\Bbb F_5$, and we wish to know the degree of this extension (dimension of $\Bbb F_5(u)$ as an $\Bbb F_5$-vector space). Consider an element $b= a_0+a_1u+a_2u^2+a_3u^3$, you can use the relation coming from the quotient (meaning $u^3=u^2+1$) to express $b$ as $$b=(a_0+a_3)+a_1u+(a_2+a_3)u^2,$$
meaning any such element can be written in terms of the  $\Bbb F_5$-basis $\{1,u,u^2\}$. Can you see how to finish the argument (taking an arbitrary element of $\Bbb F_5(u)$)?

In particular $[x]$ *is* a particular element of the quotient ring!